# bootstrap icon fonts not loading

Tags: css, fonts

I am designing a page using bootstrap v3.3.7 (latest version)

The problem is glyphicons don't load from local resource but I have them from cdn!

I get this error in console:

```
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1): status=2147746065 source: http://www/bahasoft/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
```

and for other versions of fonts as well and below one:

```
downloadable font: no supported format found (font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:5) source: (end of source list)
```

but I'm sure the fonts exist and are available at `http://www/bahasoft/fonts/`

Any idea???

sorry about my bad english

Comment: forgot to mention, `http://www/` is localhost

Comment: I've had similar problem. The solution's been to download the newest version of bootstrap and glyphicons package for this exact version.

Comment: @owczarek I've done it 2 or three times with different versions! no success

Comment: what does this give you `http://www/bahasoft/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2` when you just run this URL in the browser

Comment: @Reddy loads the page without any style and script

Comment: @Reddy screen shot of `http://www/bahasoft/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2` [here](http://i.cubeupload.com/ie4xu9.png)

Answer (score 1):

Check you nginx settings. If there is a filetype list, you should insert these font types into it also:

```
location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$
```