# Yii2 BaseUrl for bootstrap fonts

Tags: php, css, fonts, yii2, assets

I need your help guys. I changed directory for all Assets. It works properly, but not for bootstrap fonts.

For Ex: path for css and js file now is `project/www/web_assets/all.css` and Yii2 found them properly.

But it does not working for fonts.  Yii2 is looking for fonts at wrong derictrory `/var/www/tt_yii/web/assets/582582f3/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap gets used at different places. It is already configured by default by the [BootstrapAsset](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap/doc/api/2.1/yii-bootstrap-bootstrapasset) and is a dependency for other pre-defined assets. But you can override the default location.

Assuming you have the same file structure in `web_assets` as it can be found in 'vendor/bower-asset/bootstrap/dist' (contains folder css, fonts and js) you can add the following to your components configuration:

```
use yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset;

...

'components'          => [
   ...
    'assetManager' => [
        'bundles' => [
            BootstrapAsset::class => [
                'sourcePath' => null,
                'baseUrl'    => '@web/web_assets',
            ],
        ]
    ],
    ...
],
```

`@web` points to the web folder where the index.php and your `web_assets` directory file should exist as well. `sourcePath` gets set to null since baseUrl wouldn't be evaluated.

Further information about configuring the used bundles can be found at [AssetManager::$bundles](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-assetmanager#$bundles-detail) or in the  [guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-assets).

Similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28110404/57091).

Answer (score 0):

Check you nginx settings. If there is a filetype list, you should insert these font types into it also:

```
location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$
```

(Duplicate of [bootstrap icon fonts not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39288716/bootstrap-icon-fonts-not-loading/60705088#60705088) )